# Residue with transcendent function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I have to calculate the Residue at $z=i$ of this function:
$$ {e^{iz}} \over {\sqrt z (2ln(z)-i\pi )} $$

I know it's a 1st order pole and I'd like to use the traditional formula with the limit of:
$$ (z-i) {e^{iz}} \over {\sqrt z (2ln(z)-i\pi )} $$ as z->i

I am having problems calculating this limit. I can I handle residues with trascendent functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$ \lim_{z\to i} \frac{ (z-i) e^{i z}}{\sqrt{z}{ (2 \ln z- i\pi)}} = \frac{ e^{-1}}{\sqrt{i}} \left(  \lim_{z\to i} \frac{2 \ln z -i\pi} {z-i} \right)^{-1} = \frac{ e^{-1}}{\sqrt{i}} \left(  2 \frac{d}{dz} \ln (z=i)  \right)^{-1}  =\frac{ e^{-1} i}{2 \sqrt{i}} = \frac{ e^{-1} e^{i \pi/4}}{2 } ,$$
by the definition of the complex derivative and $(d/dz)\ln z=1/z$.

Comment: Note that this "trick" works in general for 1st order poles...